# PHP $_SESSION error when posting to the database

Tags: php

I am trying to create posts with a userid = to the currently logged in users id.
On page 1 I use $_SESSION to set a variable

```
$_SESSION['Userid'] = $row_getUserStuff['userid'];
```

I can call $_SESSION['Userid'] on both page 1 and page 2 with

```
echo($_SESSION['Userid']);
```

which outputs the users id, my problem is when I try to push that data to the database.
In the form I put

```
<input type="hidden" name="userid" value="<?php $_SESSION['Userid']?>" />
```

But when I try to post it I get the error

> Column 'userid' cannot be null

Comment: Stating the obvious, but have you checked whether the value is empty? Check it by viewing the HTML source and seeing what is written in the value field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="userid" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['Userid']?>" />
```

You're not actually telling PHP to output the session variable, you're just referring to it. But since it's a session variable, it doesn't need to be in the form at all, I assume there's a `$_POST['userid']` somewhere in your code to handle the form, just replace that with `$_SESSION['Userid']`.

Answer (score 7):

Don't put the session data in the form. It is pointless for the browser to have to send the server something the server already knows, and anyone can change it in an injection attack.

Instead, just access `$_SESSION['Userid']` when inserting the value into the database.

Comment: +1 Awesome answer I would've never thought of it but soo true.

Comment: Thanks, between this and JKirchartz's post I fixed it. I'm really new to PHP so his was easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<input type="hidden" name="userid" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['Userid']; ?>" />
```

I added the `echo` statement and the `;` so that no php error will be generated and the `$_SESSION['Userid']` is properly sent to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line:

```
<input type="hidden" name="userid" value="<?php $_SESSION['Userid']?>" />
```

to

```
<input type="hidden" name="userid" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['Userid']?>" />
```