# php - INSERTING the $_SESSION to the database is not inserting

Tags: php, session

In my buyBook.php I have a form that when it is submitted it will go to check_buy.php that will do the process of inserting. This is what I have in the buyBook.php

```
<div class="form-group" style="width:1px;width:1px;">
    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id']?>" />
</div>
```

And this is what I have in the check_buy.php

```
    $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
.
.
.

    $ins = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `librarydb`.`buy` (`user_id`) VALUES ('$user_id');");
```

Why it isn't inserting? I tried referencing what it is in here [PHP $_SESSION error when posting to the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9876079/php-session-error-when-posting-to-the-database) but still no luck.

Comment: You're using `session_start()` somewhere?

Comment: If this field is inside a `<form>` tag, why aren't you use `$_POST['user_id']` or `$_GET['user_id']` instead of `$_SESSION['user_id'];` inside `check_buy.php`?

Comment: You @Abra are one hell of a magician! Thanks! I didn't think of it man.

Comment: @bcesars, can i just remove the supposed to be session that will pass to `check_buy.php`? and just start adding via `session_start()`?

Comment: @WTFZane, of course you can use `session_start()`. But this input hidden field will be useless for you. You can remove it as well.

Comment: Thank you for the advice for coding ethics, i don't know how to close this question.